# AngularJS - Three way binding

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am creating a directive that can be updated both from inside and outside.
The directive is just a box containing an icon, title and loading status.
Updating this directive from outside is being done via isolate scope params. Updating it from inside will require the inner directive to require the controller of the "box directive" and use functions inside it.

I want to know if this is the best practice solving this problem (events are not an option) 8-)

**Directive**:

```
(function () {
'use strict';
var app = angular.module('mainApp');

app.directive('arBox', function () {
//        You can set the title of this box, the icon and the loading status     both from outside this directive and from 
//        inside. Use isolate scope params to update it from outside, or     require 'arBox' to update it from inside. If you are
//        updating params from inside use this directives controller methods.

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'templates/mainApp/arBox.html',
        transclude: true,
        scope: {
            boxTitle: '=',
            boxIcon: '=',
            boxLoading: '=',
        },
        controller: 'boxController',
        controllerAs: 'boxCtrl',

        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {


            scope.$watch('boxTitle', function (newVal, oldVal) {
                scope.boxCtrl.changeTitle(newVal);
            });

            scope.$watch('boxIcon', function (newVal, oldVal) {
                scope.boxCtrl.changeIcon(newVal);
            });

            scope.$watch('boxLoading', function (newVal, oldVal) {
                if (newVal) {
                    scope.boxCtrl.loadingOn();
                } else {
                    scope.boxCtrl.loadingOff();
                }
            });



        }

    }

});
})();
```

**Controller:**

```
(function () {
'use strict';
var app = angular.module('mainApp');
app.controller('boxController', function ($scope, $interval) {
    var self = this;
    this.loading = true;

    this.loadingOn = function(){self.boxLoading = true;};
    this.loadingOff = function(){self.boxLoading = false;};
    this.changeIcon = function(icon){
        self.boxIcon = icon;
    }

    this.changeTitle = function(title){
        self.boxTitle = title;
    }

});
})();
```

Comment: Can you explain why events are not an option?

Comment: Events are hard to track. How do you isolate events? Imagine a box inside a box and they both register on the same events. If an event is coming from the most inner part of the tree, both boxes will receive the event (I know you can stop propagating - but that's even harder to track and debug).

Comment: @user3043893 could you create a plunkr/fiddle..

Comment: @user3043893 To answer your question in the comments, usually events are simpler to test/debug than cross-directive bindings (imho and experience), either using an event bus (central command dispatcher), or by "bubbling up", which better disconnects your components. Since your question excludes events, I'll refrain from posting an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

The approach I would take to this particular problem would just be to re-create the directive whenever it needs changed from the outside. This would allow the inter workings of the directive to never depend on its parent thus accomplishing what the directives are used for, which is encapsulation of functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by updating inside and outside; by setting up the binding in your directive, the variable on the $scope (and your controller) get updated as well; you don't need to add your own watchers in the directive to update your controller; eg. the following is unnecessary:

```
scope.$watch('boxIcon', function (newVal, oldVal) {
    scope.boxCtrl.changeIcon(newVal);
});
```

The directive and controller share the scope, so no need to explicitly update eachother.

Comment: The title, icon and loading status are not stored in the scope, but in the controller (read the code). It is accessible from the scope using controllerAs.